# Load <select> AngularJs in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, selecteditem

I'm trying to load my  states, where it should be  with a state already informed. But I cannot carry it, how can I do this?

It works when it is an input that's okay.
but when I will show again in a form, he is not showing the state in my

In my database the data is like: Arizona

My html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label " for="state">State | {{even.state}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8">
    <span class="block input-icon "> 
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="even.state" ng-options="state.state for state in states" ng-change="change(even.state)">
            <option value="">State</option>
        </select>  
    </span>
</div>
```

Function to getState

```
var getState = function () {
        dirAPI.getState().success(function (data,status) {
            $scope.states = data[0];
        })

    };
```

Function to Load general data

```
var loadEvent = function () {
        dirAPI.getEvent().success(function (data) {
            $scope.event = data;
        });
    };
```

This is a example, when a I load the form, the Arizona did

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is not nearly enough for us to see what the issue is..please provide more details or a demo

Comment: Share us your controller please.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough could you post your controller and explain what goes wrong